# Using feature columns in an LSTM with the keras api in Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I like to build a LSTM with the keras api in Tensorflow 2.0

My label should depend on several time series including both numeric and categorical variables.

When building a normal Neural Network the feature column "feature" (https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/feature_columns)

is of great help because I don't need to do one-hot-encoding.

When switching to a LSTM is it still possible to use the feature column "feature" ?

Could you please send me a Jupyter Notebook / Tutorial on how to implement this ?

Greetings,
Jonathan

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you are looking for [tf.keras.experimental.SequenceFeatures](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/experimental/SequenceFeatures). An example is included.